# Laravel on ElasticBeanstalk 'log file permission denied' error keeps coming up even the permission is set in the .ebextensions config file

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am deploying my Laravel application to the ElasticBeanstalk environment. But I am having issue with laravel.log file permissions.

I deployed my application using "eb deploy" command. After I deployed, I access my application. But it is throwing the following error.

```
The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

To solve the issue, I ssh into the server and run the following command.

```
sudo -u root chmod 777 -R /var/app/current/storage/logs
```

The problem is solved. Now my application is working. But I deploy my application again running "be deploy" command. After the deployment, the issue popped up again. To solve the issue in a consistent way. I tried to run the command in the .ebextensions config file as follow.

```
container_commands:
  01-migrations:
    command: "php artisan migrate --force"
  02-log-storage-permissions:
    command: "sudo -u root chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage/logs/"
```

I could deploy my application. But the issue still persists. It seems like the command is not working. What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is because `container_commands` run when your application is in the staging folder. Thus, after you run `02-log-storage-permissions`, your `/var/app/current` will be replaced anyway with the staging folder. So your `chmod` wont persist.

To rectify the issue, you can try one of the **two options**:

1. Use

```
  02-log-storage-permissions:
    command: "sudo -u chmod -R 777 ./storage/logs/"
```

to change the logs in staging folder.

2. use [postdeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) hook to run your script:

> **after** the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine **deploys** the application and proxy server.